# Why am I getting NoSection Error: No Section 'common'

Tags: python, selenium, get, config

# My checkerQues.ini is:

```
[common]

retries = 2
username = myuser
```

## This is a subset of my project code, here is code related to problem

#  My python script is:

```
import os
import ast
import ConfigParser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

config.read('checkerQues.ini')
```

## Get values from config file

```
RETRIES = int(config.get("common", "retries"))
USERNAME = config.get("common", "username")
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: as soon as RETRIES = executes

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation of `config.read` it mentions

> read(self, filenames) method of ConfigParser.ConfigParser instance
>
> Read and parse a filename or a list of filenames.
>
> Files that cannot be opened are silently ignored; this is
>       designed so that you can specify a list of potential
>       configuration file locations (e.g. current directory, user's
>       home directory, systemwide directory), and all existing
>       configuration files in the list will be read.  A single
>       filename may also be given.
>
> Return list of successfully read files.

So you should use

```
print (config.read('checkerQues.ini'))
```

To make sure you config is present in current folder and is loaded. The exception later indicates the ini file was never read